# setOneShotPreviewCallback() on a Camera object, cropped version of the preview Image

Tags: java, android, camera, arrays, android-camera

I am developing a fairly process hungry application which I need to take an image and save it every time a button is pressed. On pressing the button I trigger the `setOneShotPreviewCallback()` method of the camera object to get a `byte[]` representing the image at that moment. At the moment after this I take this `byte[]` and convert that to a bitmap using a YUVImage object which is very heavy on the processor. To reduce this I crop the image using:

```
Rect rect = new Rect(4*w/10, 0, 9*w/10, h);
final ByteArrayOutputStream output_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
yuv_image.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, output_stream);
```

I would like to know if I can do this only using the `byte[]` and not have to convert it to the YUV Image? like before the callback is triggered the Rect is created and the `byte[]` is only populated with the image data inside that Rect?

Comment: I don't understand this part "On pressing the button I trigger the `setOneShotPreviewCallback()`" . Its a callback, you can't trigger it.. and I don't think it is giving you the correct raw image when you actually perform the capture. The callback can be called anytime.. see the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setOneShotPreviewCallback(android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set up PreviewFormat:

```
parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
```